# Combining two arrays of same size and returns sum

Tags: javascript, arrays, functional-programming

In Javascript (or any other programming language with a functional-like syntax), if I have two arrays of the same size, say
`a = [1,2,3,4]` and `b=[5,6,7,8]`, what is the most efficient way to have the following result:
`c=[6,8,10,12]`.

For now, I do:

`a.map(function(x,i){
  return x+b[i]
})`

but ideally I would like a solution that doesn't involve the use of indexes.

Comment: I'm pretty sure that is the most efficient method.

Comment: Why do you want to avoid indices? I guess you could use a recursive function which shifts the first numbers, sums them and pushes the result to the sum array, calls itself recursively, and then unshifts the numbers. I don't recommend it, though.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

ES5 array methods are great, but old `for` loops are faster.

```js
var sum = Array(a.length);
for(var i=0; i<a.length; ++i)
  sum[i] = a[i] + b[i];
```

Comment: .. any clue without the use of indices though?

Comment: `for` loops are imperative, not functional

Comment: Also, if `a` is longer than `b`, you may get unintended/undesirable behavior; `[6,8,10,12,NaN,NaN,...,NaN]`

Comment: @naomik True, but question says "two arrays of the same size".

Answer (score 5):

> **Warning**: [@dangor](https://stackoverflow.com/a/32019957/633183)'s answer mutates one of the inputs which is pretty awful imo. My answer will give you your result without yielding side effects.

<kbd>[Babel demo](http://babeljs.io/repl/#?experimental=true&evaluate=true&loose=true&spec=false&code=let%20zip%20%3D%20(xs%2C%20ys)%20%3D%3E%20%7B%0A%20%20let%20iter%20%3D%20(zs%2C%20%5Bx%2C%20...xs%5D%2C%20%5By%2C%20...ys%5D)%20%3D%3E%0A%20%20%20%20(!x%20%7C%7C%20!y)%20%3F%20zs%20%3A%20iter(zs.concat(%5B%5Bx%2Cy%5D%5D)%2C%20xs%2C%20ys)%0A%20%20return%20iter(%5B%5D%2C%20xs%2C%20ys)%3B%0A%7D%0A%0Alet%20add%20%3D%20(x%2Cy)%20%3D%3E%20x%20%2B%20y%3B%0Alet%20reduce%20%3D%20f%20%3D%3E%20i%20%3D%3E%20xs%20%3D%3E%20xs.reduce(f%2C%20i)%3B%0Alet%20sum%20%3D%20reduce(add)(0)%3B%0A%0Alet%20a%20%3D%20%5B1%2C2%2C3%2C4%5D%3B%0Alet%20b%20%3D%20%5B5%2C6%2C7%2C8%5D%3B%0A%0Alet%20result%20%3D%20zip(a%2Cb).map(sum)%3B%0A%0Aconsole.log(result)%3B%0A)</kbd> — The code below is written using ES6. If you want the ES5 code, view the right-hand panel in the Babel REPL.

---

I would recommend a `zip` function first. This function will take two arrays and create an array of tuples.

```
// zip :: [a] -> [b] -> [(a,b)]
let zip = (xs, ys) => {
  let iter = (zs, [x, ...xs], [y, ...ys]) =>
    (!x || !y) ? zs : iter(zs.concat([[x,y]]), xs, ys)
  return iter([], xs, ys);
};

let a = [1,2,3,4];
let b = [5,6,7,8];

zip(a,b); //=> [[1,5], [2,6], [3,7], [4,8]]
```

Now you can use `map` on each tuple

```
zip(a,b).map(t => t[0] + t[1]);
//=> [6,8,10,12]
```

---

So that last bit looks a little nasty, but we can clean that up if we continue to build some more functional building blocks

If we notice, in our mapping function, all we're doing is summing the elements of the array. We can avoid being over-specific by creating functions to do this.

Let's first look at how we'd sum an array ...

```
[1,2,3,4].reduce((x, y) => x + y, 0); //=> 10
```

OK, so the first thing we can improve here is the closure. That function is simply an `add` function.

```
let add = (x,y) => x + y;
[1,2,3,4].reduce(add, 0); //=> 10
```

But how would we use this to improve our original code ?

```
// original code
zip(a,b).map(t => t[0] + t[1]);      //=> [6,8,10,12]

// improvement #1
zip(a,b).map(t => t.reduce(add, 0)); //=> [6,8,10,12]
```

OK, not much of an improvement yet, and it's not going to get better until we fix that `reduce` function. JavaScript forces us to call reduce using this notation: `obj.reduce(fn, i)`. This order of arguments kinda sucks, so let's fix that

```
// improvement #2
let reduce = f => i => xs => xs.reduce(f, i);
zip(a,b).map(reduce(add)(0)); //=> [6,8,10,12]
```

Finally, instead of using `reduce(add)(0)` every time we wanted to sum an array, we could just define a `sum` function

```
// improvement #3
let sum = reduce(add)(0);
zip(a,b).map(sum); //=> [6,8,10,12]
```

---

**All together now ...**

```
let zip = (xs, ys) => {
  let iter = (zs, [x, ...xs], [y, ...ys]) =>
    (!x || !y) ? zs : iter(zs.concat([[x,y]]), xs, ys)
  return iter([], xs, ys);
};

let add = (x,y) => x + y;
let reduce = f => i => xs => xs.reduce(f, i);
let sum = reduce(add)(0);

let a = [1,2,3,4];
let b = [5,6,7,8];

let result = zip(a,b).map(sum);

console.log(result);
//=> [6,8,10,12]
```

---

Sure, this results in more overall code than other solutions, but the point of the exercise is that by the time you've arrived at your solution using this method, you have **four** functions that you can now repurpose for other code: `zip`, `add`, `reduce`, and `sum` are all quite versatile; all of which are [total](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Partial_function#Total_function)
and [pure](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pure_function).

Lastly, the use of these functions affords us a [point-free](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tacit_programming) solution which exhibits a much stronger *declarative* dialect than an *imperative* one.

I hope this has helped you see how you can assemble several smaller functions to achieve your goals — all **without** having to do silly things like resort to imperative `for` loops or surrendering to reckless side effects like mutating inputs.

Comment: this looks fancy and awesome but I wonder the performance of it compare to imperative approach?

Comment: @BryanChen it doesn't really matter. First, you're comparing apples to oranges; A functional answer is not an imperative one and the OP is looking for a functional answer. Second, It's a fraction of a second vs a fraction of a second. Unless the code is in a high-volume loop or something, there's no point in such optimizations. A much more valid concern is code maintainability and readability; How would you rate `zip(a,b).map(sum)` vs `var sum = Array(a.length); for(var i=0; i<a.length; ++i) sum[i] = a[i] + b[i];` ?

Comment: Lastly, there's nothing "fancy" about the code in my answer. It's just a repeated pattern of identifying reusable functions and using functions to build other functions. This is the essence of the Functional Programming paradigm, if I'm not mistaken.

Comment: to be honest, my non-functional mind reads the second version better. maybe I should start writing FP code bit more

Comment: the fancy part for me is the implementation of `zip` function. `(zs, [x, ...xs], [y, ...ys])` took me a while to understand

Comment: That's ES6 [destructuring assignment](http://babeljs.io/docs/learn-es2015/#destructuring); not inherently a part of functional programming, but certainly useful for us here.

Comment: OP asked for "...the most efficient way to have the following result" with a functional approach (or more specifically, an approach that doesn't use indices) being a secondary goal ("ideally", he said).

Comment: How are we measuring efficiency? I can read and understand `zip(a,b).map(sum)` very efficiently. Also it's functional. And it doesn't use indices.

Answer (score 2):

There's another shorter option using using Array.map():

```
a = [1,2,3,4];
b = [5,6,7,8];

var result = a.map(function(item){
  return item + b.shift();
})
```

Comment: Note this will erase `b`

Answer (score 0):

No indices? Don't know if this is more efficient than your original code, but you can make a couple of improvements to thecodeparadox's answer, which already assumes you don't need to keep the original arrays.

1. use pop instead of shift (followed by a final reverse)
2. use a loop instead of recursion

something like:

```
function doSum(a, b) {
  var sum = [];
  while (a.length) sum.push(a.pop() + b.pop());
  return sum.reverse();
}
```

Comment: this answer mutates inputs unnecessarily

Comment: @naomik, first off, i noted that it was doing that; second, the OP didn't say anything about keeping the inputs -- just asked for efficiency, followed by not using indices.

Comment: When you visit the dentist to treat a toothache, would the dentist suggest removing your teeth as a cure for your pain ?

Comment: @naomik, wow, that is a really exaggerated metaphor. It is highly unusual that you won't be needing your teeth anymore; it is not at all unusual to have intermediate results in arrays that you don't need anymore -- it's a time honored optimization route if you know you won't be needing the intermediate results. Even so, there are cases when the dentist suggests removing teeth.