# Sum array of arrays (matrix) vertically efficiently/elegantly

Tags: javascript, arrays, data-structures, functional-programming

In Javascript, if I have an array of arrays representing a matrix, say

```
x = [
    [1,2,3,4],
    [5,6,7,8],
    [9,10,11,12]
];
```

summing it "horizontally" is easy and can be done like

```
x.map(function(y){
  return y.reduce(function(a,b){
      return a+b;
  });
});
```

or

```
x.map(y => y.reduce((a, b) => a+b));
```

Now I would like to compute the "vertical" sum, which can be done

```
x.reduce(function(a, b){
    return a.map(function(v,i){
        return v+b[i];
    });
});
```

or

```
x.reduce((a, b) => a.map((v,i) => v+b[i]));
```

But I am not happy with this version and I wish there were something nicer, more elegant and more straightforward. Maybe an easy way to transpose the matrix beforehand? anyone?

```js
const x = [
  [1, 2, 3, 4],
  [5, 6, 7, 8],
  [9, 10, 11, 12],
];

const a = x.map((y) => y.reduce((a, b) => a + b));
const b = x.reduce((a, b) => a.map((v, i) => v + b[i]));
const c = x.flat().reduce((a , b) => a + b)

console.log('Summing horizontally: '  + JSON.stringify(a));
console.log('Summing vertically: ' + JSON.stringify(b));
console.log('Summing whole array: ' + JSON.stringify(c));
```

Note that I asked a similar question a few days ago ([link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32019544/combining-two-arrays-of-same-size-and-returns-sum?noredirect=1#comment51941758_32019544)) but that lacked the bigger picture.

Comment: What exactly do you think is wrong with that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you are unhappy that there is no native `zip` function, because that's what your `reduce` in the `map` is essentially doing. You'll either have to implement it yourself or import it from a library like [Ramda](http://ramdajs.com/0.17/docs/#zipWith), in order to write elegant code like this:

```
var verticalSum = x.map(R.zipWith(function(a,b){ return a+b; }));
```

If you are looking for an efficient solution, there's basically no better way than explicit loops.

Answer (score 28):

You could sum the values at the same index.

Use: `array.reduce(sum)`

```js
var sum = (r, a) => r.map((b, i) => a[i] + b);

console.log([[1, 2, 3, 4], [5, 6, 7, 8], [9, 10, 11, 12]].reduce(sum));
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```

Answer (score 9):

```
arrayOfArrays = [
  [1,2,3,4],
  [5,6,7,8],
  [9,10,11,12]
];

arrayOfArrays.reduce(function(array1, array2) {
  return array1.map(function(value, index) {
    return value + array2[index];
  });
});
```

For my own benefit, and hopefully the benefit of others, I wanted to explain how the nested `reduce`/`map` methods function to perform the vertical summation of an array of equal length arrays. This is the perfectly acceptable version offered by the OP.

The `reduce` method applies a function against an accumulator and each value of the array from left to right to reduce it to a single value ([MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/Reduce)).

The case of this example, in the the first iteration the first two arrays are passed into the callback function for `reduce` as `array1` and `array2`. The return value for the callback function is the result of the `map` method applied to array1.

`map` returns a new array with the results of calling the provided function on every element of the array. ([MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map)).

So `map` iterates each value in `array1` and adds it to the value in `array2` at the same index position. These results are pushed to a new array which is then returned to the `reduce` method.

The array of sums that was just returned now becomes the new `array1` and `reduce` invokes its function passing in the new `array1` and the next array as the new `array2`.

This is repeated until we run out of arrays in `arrayOfArrays`

Starting with:

```
arrayOfArrays = [
  [1,2,3,4],
  [5,6,7,8],
  [9,10,11,12]
];
```

The first iteration of reduce passes:

```
array1 [1,2,3,4]
array2 [5,6,7,8]
```

To the callback function for `reduce`.  The return value for `reduce`
is a new array derived by using `map` to add each value of `array1` to
the value of `array2` in the same position:

```
array1 [1,2,3,4]
array2 [5,6,7,8]
return [6,8,10,12]
```

This value is returned to the `reduce` method and becomes the new 
`array1`. `array1` and next array (`array2`) are then again passed into the 
`reduce` callback function and summed by the `map` method:

```
array1 [6,8,10,12]
array2 [9,10,11,12]
return [15,18,21,24]   // returned by map()
```

Answer (score 1):

Really elegant only for square matrix from me.

```
   x = [[1,2,3,4],
        [5,6,7,8],
        [9,10,11,12]
    ];
    var sum = function(arr) {
      return arr.reduce(function(a, b){ return a + b; }, 0);
    };

    x.map(function(row, i) {
      return sum(x.map(function(row) { return row[i]; }));
    });
```

http://jsfiddle.net/btux9s2d/ example with console log.

for any size matrix, not so elegant, but maybe will help you on your way:
http://jsfiddle.net/btux9s2d/2/

Comment: Matrix in your first example isn't square ;)

Answer (score 1):

You can use recursivity to sum arrays of any dimensions with this function:

```
function sumRecursiveArray(arr) {
  return arr.reduce(function(acc, value) {
    return acc + (Array.isArray(value) ? sumRecursiveArray(value) : value);
  }, 0);
}

var sum = sumRecursiveArray([[1,1,1],[2,2,2]]);
console.log(sum); // 9
```

Comment: I don't want the sum of the array of arrays but the sums of the columns. Thank you for your answer though!

Answer (score 0):

```js
x = [[1,2,3,4],
    [5,6,7,8],
    [9,10,11,12]
];

var y = x.flat(Infinity); 
//y = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12]

console.log(y.reduce((total, num) => {return total + num}, 0)); 
//78
```

Comment: It's about summing array of arrays. Finally we can use 'flat'.

Comment: hi, this is not what I asked for

Answer (score 0):

The algorithms presented above do not work if there is an empty array inside the matrix, I share a solution that solves the problem.

```
console.log(sumVertical([[1,2],[1,3],[1,4]]))

console.log(sumVertical([[],[1,3],[1,4]]))



function sumVertical(values){
    
let result = []
    
for (let index = 0; index < values.length; index++) {
  for (let index2 = 0; index2 < values[index].length; index2++) {
    result[index2] = (result[index2] == undefined ? 0 : result[index2]) + values[index][index2]
  }
}

return result

}
```