# Sum array values in object of arrays

Tags: javascript, arrays, angularjs, multidimensional-array

I'm looking to sum positions in an object of arrays. Essentially, each number represents a yearly amount for an expense line item, and I need to sum these up for each year. The object looks like this (see below) and the result should be an array which = [1500, 1900, 2400] given the object below.

```
x = [{
      "HVAC": [100, 200, 300, 400],
      "foundation": [500, 600, 700, 800],
      "roof": [900, 1000, 1100, 1200]
    }];
```

If the arrays weren't named, and instead looked like:

```
x = [
          [100, 200, 300, 400],
          [500, 600, 700, 800],
          [900, 1000, 1100, 1200]
        ];
```

Then this function would do what I want (thanks to this post [Sum array of arrays (matrix) vertically efficiently/elegantly](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32139773/sum-array-of-arrays-matrix-vertically-efficiently-elegantly)):

```
 $scope.reserveTotals = x.reduce(function(a, b) {
      return a.map(function(v, i) {
        return v + b[i];
      });
    });
```

As it stands, I need to keep the original structure and am just struggling to adapt that function do what I need. Any help appreciated!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A slightly different solution.

```js
var x = { "HVAC": [100, 200, 300, 400], "foundation": [500, 600, 700, 800], "roof": [900, 1000, 1100, 1200] },
    result = Object.keys(x).reduce(function (r, k) {
        x[k].forEach(function (a, i) {
            r[i] = (r[i] || 0) + a;
        });
        return r;
    }, []);

document.write('<pre>' + JSON.stringify(result, 0, 4) + '</pre>');
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use `for...in` loop and `reduce`

```js
x = [{
  "HVAC": [100, 200, 300, 400],
  "foundation": [500, 600, 700, 800],
  "roof": [900, 1000, 1100, 1200]
}];

for(var p in x[0]) {
  x[0][p] = x[0][p].reduce((a, b) => { return a + b});
}

console.log(x)
```